# Bluetooth don't work: "HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported."

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth

My bluetooth is not working. It's like the same problem with all people that i see here, "no default controller avaliable", but i tried anything but nothing was working.

my dmesg:

```
sudo dmesg |egrep -i "wifi|blue|fw|firm"
[    2.563811] ata1.00: ATA-9: SSD 240GB, FW200326, max UDMA/133
[   12.073130] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   13.278796] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.130 Family ID: 16
[   13.299519] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 53.26 Binary ID: 3
[   21.787126] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129650.702:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1168 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   21.799589] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129650.714:130): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" class="net" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1167 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   21.846680] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129650.762:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1167 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   22.366167] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129651.282:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" class="net" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1653 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   22.366409] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129651.282:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1653 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   22.368504] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129651.282:134): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1654 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   22.650265] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129651.566:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" class="net" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1704 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[   22.650456] audit: type=1400 audit(1690129651.566:136): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1704 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  219.003648] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  219.003681] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[  219.003683] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  219.003686] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  219.003689] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  219.003693] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  219.024251] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=6 rev=0709; LMP ver=6 subver=0709; manufacturer=10
[  219.024257] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  219.324248] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  219.324261] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  219.324272] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  219.437786] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[  219.437797] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[  219.437802] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[  220.109828] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2003 failed: -19
[  226.470340] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=6 rev=0709; LMP ver=6 subver=0709; manufacturer=10
[  226.470357] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  226.470364] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[  226.470465] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[  226.470473] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[  226.470478] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[  228.497537] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[  228.497539] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2003 failed: -110
[  252.967683] audit: type=1107 audit(1690129881.882:158): pid=1037 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=5671 label="snap.brave.brave" peer_pid=5246 peer_label="unconfined"
[  327.762425] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[ 1674.336648] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=6 rev=0709; LMP ver=6 subver=0709; manufacturer=10
[ 1674.336654] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[ 1674.336660] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[ 1674.336663] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 1674.336664] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 1674.336666] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[ 1676.356017] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2003 failed: -110
[ 1688.815219] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=6 rev=0709; LMP ver=6 subver=0709; manufacturer=10
[ 1688.815225] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[ 1688.815230] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[ 1688.815232] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 1688.815234] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 1688.815235] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[ 1690.853400] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 1690.853403] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2003 failed: -110
[ 2032.174959] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[ 2032.174970] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[ 2032.174976] Bluetooth: DynamicAlloc pci_device_id table at 0x000000007714d335 with size 80
[ 2032.174985] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[ 2032.174991] Bluetooth: Convert: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[ 2032.174995] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[ 2032.175000] Bluetooth: pci_device_id: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
```

Comment: You have internal wifi and USB?

Comment: Your system builder used a WiFi/Bluetooth  chip (`hci0`) that doesn't work according to Standard ("`Unbranded CSR clone detected`"). It's as if the chip claims to be version 6, but when the computer sends a version 6 command ("`Delete Stored Link Key" (reset the chip's Link Key), the chip does not recognize the command.